# Writing SQL query without count

Tags: sql, count

Can anyone help me how to write this query without using count?
"Some directors directed more than one movie. For all such directors, return the titles of all movies directed by them, along with the director name. Sort by director name, then movie title.(without COUNT.)

```
mID | title                  | director
--------------------------------------
101 |Gone with the Wind      |Victor Fleming
102 |Star Wars               |George Lucas
103 |The Sound of Music      |Robert Wise  
104 |E.T.                    |Steven Spielberg
105 |Titanic                 |James Cameron
106 |Snow White              |<null>
107 |Avatar                  |James Cameron
108 |Raiders of the Lost Ark |Steven Spielberg
```

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: what to do of <null> in director name?

Answer (score 3):

You can compare for each director the min and max of the mid.
If they are different - there is more than 1.

```
Select mid, title, director
From tbl 
where director in (Select director
                                 From tbl
                                 Group by director
                                 Having max(mid) > min (mid))
order by director, title
```

Comment: Another good idea. UV from me. You could also use 1+ as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a CTE or sub-query. Not using `COUNT()` is pretty silly though. It's an ideal case for such an aggregate.

```
with cte as(
select
    director
    ,title
    ,row_number() over (partition by director order by title) as rn
from
    yourTable)

select
   director,
   title 
from cte
where director in (select director from cte where rn > 1)
order by 
   director, 
   title
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select director, sum(1) as cnt
      from t
      group by director
     ) d
     on t.director = d.director
where cnt > 1
order by director, title;
```